# Why my code for .htaccess file is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to modify following dynamic URL to SEF URL:
http://sampleurl.com/en/movie-details.php?id=1001

URL: URL should be like following:
http://sampleurl.com/movie/id-1001/

Please help me..... here's my code... I am using godaddy server

```
Options -MultiViews
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On

# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage

RewriteRule .* movie-details.php [F]

#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/movie-details\.php

RewriteRule .* /en/movie-details.php?id=$1  [L]


    # Removes index.php from URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*movie-details\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)movie-details\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /movie-details.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d

RewriteRule ^movie/id-([0-9]+)/$ /movie-details.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```